# high school senior A division contest question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The product of my age 7 years ago and my age 7 years from now is a positive perfect square. Compute my age now.
I set up the equation, $(x+7)(x-7)=a^2$, so $x^2 -49= a^2$.
So I know that x has to be bigger than 7.
But I don't know what to do next... Please help me! 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You have $x^2-49=y^2$, which can be rearranged to give $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=7^2$. What are possible values of $x+y$ and $x-y$?